# Windows 10 Upgrade and Nvidia GeForce GT 430

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I upgraded to windows 10, but the display adapter was not working properly. I got the latest update from nvidia (353.62) but still there are some issues.
When I restart the machine after booting the start menu and search is not working. when I go to device manager and uninstall the Display Adaptor, windows automatically install it back and all good. but after restarting the machine again same thing. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting "graphics has successfully recovered from a stopped working state" type message over and over until I uninstalled **all but** the 353.62 graphics drivers. 
I took out the nVidia audio, phys x, update software, and 3D stuff using Revo Uninstall in order to eliminate left behind registry and folder files the standard uninstall left behind.

That seemed to do the trick, but I have no idea why. At any rate everything seems to still work without the constant errors.

I suspect there is some collision between the graphics drivers and the new (19.0.0.185) Adobe Flash using Firefox 41.01.185

All this was on an old Dell Optiplex 360 running win 10 (86) upgrade with . GT430 graphics card and 4 gigs ram.